# How to get AS400 Joblist and their statuses using ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ibm-connections

I have  given  AS400 Server details and Credential now I have to connect that server and get the list of jobs running in that server and their respective statuses using ASP.NET/C#. Please guide me how to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: How about some code Raj?

Comment: I have searched, is there any API does this or Anyway to run this "WRKJOB" command through C# but no luck

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23269918/how-to-retrieve-a-specific-joblist-from-the-as400 something similar to this , i need to get job list and respective run status

Comment: look for ASP.NET jt400